# ffmpeg: handle videos with changing resolution

Tags: ffmpeg

I write a program, which concatenates input list of videos programmatically. The problem is that these videos are parts of a recorded stream, and their resolution may change few times within the same file.
Currently, if that happens, ffmpeg fails, saying that it's not possible to concat files with different resolutions. Is there a way to make ffmpeg handling this automatically? A good solution would be selective scaling of frames with unexpected resolution.

Here is a listing:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mkv -i 1.mka
-max_muxing_queue_size 10000
-preset veryfast -r 30 -crf 20 -b:a 96000 -vbr on
-strict experimental
-filter_complex '
color=black:s=320x240:d=7ms[black0];
aevalsrc=0:d=15ms[silence1];
[black0][0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[video];
[1][silence1]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[audio]'
-map [video] -map [audio] -c:v libvpx -c:a libopus output.webm

ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_9 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2021-03-02T13:44:03.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:48.41, start: 0.710000, bitrate: 757 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 320x240, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 120 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
Input #1, matroska,webm, from '1.mka':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2021-03-02T13:44:03.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:48.40, start: 0.703000, bitrate: 38 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio
Codec AVOption preset (Configuration preset) specified for output file #0 (output.webm) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (vp8) -> concat:in1:v0
  Stream #1:0 (opus) -> concat:in0:a0
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libvpx)
  concat -> Stream #0:1 (libopus)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvpx @ 0x7fe08a80bc00] v1.9.0
[libvpx @ 0x7fe08a80bc00] Bitrate not specified for constrained quality mode, using default of 256kbit/sec
Output #0, webm, to 'output.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 256 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libvpx
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: opus (libopus), 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libopus
[Parsed_color_0 @ 0x7fe089815940] EOF timestamp not reliable
[Parsed_concat_2 @ 0x7fe088501980] Input link in0:v0 parameters (size 640x480, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (320x240, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_2 @ 0x7fe088501980] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[libopus @ 0x7fe08a810c00] 1 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

Here is the only such video with "floating" resolution, which cannot be concatenated with 320x240 color filter.

Comment: Show your ffmpeg command and the complete log.

Comment: I have added a log.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not wrong, you just want to merge videos which can be of different resolutions, then this will work for you, take a look at given code:

Explanation: Here, i have created `pad` (one type of container) in which i'm fitting videos so that every video will automatically fits into given pad size, plus one more thing if any of your video is mute than command will fails so that i added new method `isVideoHaveAudioTrack()` which checks if video have audio or not and if video doesn't have any audio then we have to add silent audio so that out command can work successfully.

```
private boolean isVideoHaveAudioTrack(String path) {

    boolean isAudioTrackAvailable;
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(path);
        String hasAudioStr = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_AUDIO);
        isAudioTrackAvailable = hasAudioStr != null && hasAudioStr.equals("yes");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isAudioTrackAvailable = false;
    }

    return isAudioTrackAvailable;
}


public static LinkedList<String> mergeVideo(ArrayList<Video> selectedVideos, String silencedAudio, String filepath) {

    String str3 = "";
    StringBuilder str4 = new StringBuilder(str3);
    StringBuilder str5 = new StringBuilder(str4.toString());

    boolean isAnyMuteVideo = false;

    LinkedList<String> commandList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedVideos.size(); i++) {
        commandList.add("-i");
        commandList.add(selectedVideos.get(i).getLocation());
        if (!isVideoHaveAudioTrack(selectedVideos.get(i).getPath())) {
            isAnyMuteVideo = true;
        }
        if (i == selectedVideos.size() - 1) {
            if (isAnyMuteVideo) {
                commandList.add("-i");
                commandList.add(silencedAudio);
            }
        }

        String str6 = str3 + "[" + i + ":v]fps=25,scale=w=min(iw*" + "1280" + "/ih\\," + "720" + "):h=min(" +
                "1280" + "\\,ih*" + "720" + "/iw), pad=w=" + "720" +
                ":h=" + "1280" + ":x=( " + "720" + "-iw)/2:y=(" + "1280" + "-ih)/2,format=yuv420p,setsar=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v" + i + "];";

        if (isVideoHaveAudioTrack(selectedVideos.get(i).getPath())) {
            str4.append("[").append(i).append(":a]aformat=channel_layouts=stereo:sample_rates=44100,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a").append(i).append("];");
            str5.append("[v").append(i).append("][a").append(i).append("]");
        } else {
            str4.append("[").append(selectedVideos.size()).append(":a]aformat=channel_layouts=stereo:sample_rates=44100,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a").append(selectedVideos.size()).append("];");
            str5.append("[v").append(i).append("][a").append(selectedVideos.size()).append("]");
        }
        str3 = str6;
    }
    commandList.add("-filter_complex");
    commandList.add(str3 + str4 + str5 + "concat=n=" + selectedVideos.size() + ":v=1:a=1[v][a]");
    commandList.add("-map");
    commandList.add("[v]");
    commandList.add("-map");
    commandList.add("[a]");
    commandList.add("-c:v");
    commandList.add("libx264");
    commandList.add("-c:a");
    commandList.add("aac");
    commandList.add("-preset");
    commandList.add("ultrafast");
    commandList.add(filepath);
    return commandList;
}
```

Try this and tell us if this will works for you or not with ffmpeg logs so that we can help you by improving above answer.